# Making the basic accumulator in Real World OCaml use Async

Tags: asynchronous, ocaml

I was going through Real World OCaml and wanted to make the [program in "A Complete Program"](https://realworldocaml.org/v1/en/html/a-guided-tour.html#a-complete-program) use `Async`. It works now, but I'm wondering how idiomatic it is, and if I'm doing anything weird?

```
open Core.Std
open Async.Std

let read_and_accumulate () =
  Reader.lines (Lazy.force Reader.stdin)
  |> Pipe.filter ~f:(Fn.non String.is_empty)
  |> Pipe.map ~f:Float.of_string
  |> Pipe.fold ~init:0. ~f:(fun x y -> return (x +. y))

let () =
  ignore (read_and_accumulate ()
          >>| printf "Result is %f\n"
          >>| fun () -> exit 0);
  ignore (Scheduler.go ())
```

Also, I feel like I should be able to `Fn.compose return (+.)` for the `Pipe.fold` line but it doesn't work. Why not?

Answer (score 1):

It is totally idiomatic and pretty code. My personal style is to put the pipe operators to the end, as they are, at their essence, just functional semicolons, e.g.,

```
let read_and_accumulate () =
  Reader.lines (Lazy.force Reader.stdin)  |> 
  Pipe.filter ~f:(Fn.non String.is_empty) |> 
  Pipe.map ~f:Float.of_string |> 
  Pipe.fold ~init:0. ~f:(fun x y -> return (x +. y))
```

With such approach every line starts with a word, not the punctuation that helps the readability.

What concerning the compose function, it didn't work for you because `(+.)` is binary (in fact it is not binary, but it is a function that returns a function). So, when you compose a `return` function that has type `'a -> 'b`, with some function `f : 'c -> 'c -> 'c`, then you actually has a type `('c -> 'c) -> 'b`, where `('c -> 'c)` is the return type of function `f`. Note, the parenthesis. The `('c -> 'c) -> 'b` is not equivalent to `'c -> 'c -> 'b`. The first type describes a function, that takes a function and returns a value (i.e., apply-style function), and the latter type describes a function that take a value, and returns a function, that takes another value and computes the result (the curried binary function).